# Enter button issue in Firefox

Tags: javascript, events, firefox, onchange, onkeydown

I have a text field which will accepts only numbers. When the user types any characters and moves out of the `textfield`,
using onchange I am checking whether user have entered Number or characters. So when user press tab , using onchange the value is checked.
When the user press Enter button, it is set as `window.event.keycode =9;` as IE supports this. To make it work in other browsers,
I have written logic to move the focus whenever the user presses the enter button.

The problem which I am facing is in Firefox, when the user presses enter button in the text field, now `onchange` is called as well as onsubmit is also called, which makes my page to refresh again.
The logic which I have written to move the focus to next item , is also working. But I don't know why, `onchange` and `onsubmit` is called.
This project composes of huge amount of code, thats why I am not able to post a piece of code.
Any idea why it is working like this?

Comment: we are not psychic...how can we help if we don't see code?

Comment: My chrystal ball says: _Add `event.preventDefault()` into your validating function if `ENTER` was pressed_.

Comment: Hi @imulsion. Please check this in IE and also in Firefox. http://jsfiddle.net/hQ86t/1/

Comment: Hi @Teemu. I have tried that too. Its quite weird in Firefox. Check this in IE and Firefox. http://jsfiddle.net/GBGb7/

Comment: @Cyril Looks like in FF (21.0) `onsubmit` would fire before `onkeydown`, but that doesn't make any sense!? I haven't Firebug at hands right now, with Error console only it's hopeless to investigate this properly...

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers have a global event object, other send the event object to the event handler as a parameter. Chrome and Internet Exlporer uses the former, Firefox uses the latter.

Some browsers use keyCode, others use charCode.

Enter key code is 13

Comment: Which One ? I am not able to find the link

Answer (score 0):

```
    function Numberonly() {

                var reg = /^((\d{1,8}(\.\d{0,5})?%)|(\d{1,8}(\.\d{0,5})?))$/;

                if (!reg.test(($("#txtunitId").val()))) {
                    $("#txtunitId").val('');
                    return false;
                }
            }


 <input type="text" id="txtunitId" style="float: left;" onkeyup="Numberonly();" />
```

jsfiddle.net/hQ86t/20

Comment: Actually these logic is already written in the onchange. I don't want to write it in keydown or keyup

Comment: The issue is that FF submits the form when pressing enter on input, not the validating itself.

Comment: So what you are saying is block the flow when the enter key is up. So that, the onchange also will work successfully. Am I right Teemu ?

Comment: Hi Jaimin. I saw your code.. But I want to include the onchange event too. That is the main problem

Comment: You need like this.I don't know why is not working on jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/hQ86t/21/